# Why are multiple functions being called for this tkinter event binding? (solved)

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, events, listbox

The code snippet below creates two listboxes. I've written the code so that:

- An item selected from the 'Available' list is transferred to the 'Selected' list upon clicking the item (controlled via the OnASelect method)
- The index of the item that is transferred is conserved in the 'Available' list (it is replaced with an empty string)
- An item selected from the 'Selected' list is transferred BACK to the 'Available' list upon clicking the item
- Because the index of the 'Available' list is conserved, items are always transferred back in the original order regardless of what order they are clicked.

Here's my issue:

- Despite the widget working as intended, I'm still getting an unnecessary function call to OnASelect upon transferring items BACK to the 'Available' list, which causes an Index Error. This widget is intended for a larger project I'm working on and I want to avoid this causing problems down the line.
- For troubleshooting purposes, I've written my code so that when a transfer occurs, a print statement is sent out displaying either 'The A>S function was activated' or 'The S>A function was activated'.
- Output upon transferring an item from 'Available' to 'Selected':

```
The A>S function was activated
```

- Output upon transferring an item from 'Selected' to 'Available':

```
The S>A function was activated
The A>S function was activated
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "x:/Mouselight Data Management/GUI_Branch/GUI_Menu_Related/Test/test2.py", line 29, in OnASelect
    AselectionIndex = int(event.widget.curselection()[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
PS X:\Mouselight Data Management\GUI_Branch> The A>S function was activate
```

I've wasted way too much time trying to figure out why it's doing this and I'm stumped. Any help with this issue would be much appreciated!

Ps. I know that adding an 'if event.widget.curselection():' at the start of the OnASelect method bypasses the error, but I want to prevent the multiple function call to begin with.

The full code:

```
from tkinter import *

class DependentLists(Tk):
    def __init__(self): 
        Tk.__init__(self)
        
        self.mainframe = Frame(self)
        self.mainframe.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, anchor=CENTER)

        completelabel = Label(self.mainframe, text = "Available:")
        completelabel.grid(row=2, column = 0)
        selectedlabel = Label(self.mainframe, text = "Selected:")
        selectedlabel.grid(row=2, column = 1)
        
        self.Available = Listbox(self.mainframe)
        self.Available.grid(row=3, column = 0)
        self.AList = []
        for i in range(6):
            self.Available.insert(END,i)
            self.AList.append(i)
        self.Available.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.OnASelect)

        self.Selected = Listbox(self.mainframe)
        self.Selected.grid(row=3, column = 1)
        self.Selected.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.OnSSelect)

    def OnASelect(self, event):
        print('The A>S function was activated')
        AselectionIndex = int(event.widget.curselection()[0])
        Aselection = event.widget.get(AselectionIndex)
        self.Available.delete(AselectionIndex)
        self.Available.insert(AselectionIndex,'')
        self.Selected.insert(END, Aselection)

    def OnSSelect(self, event):
        print('The S>A function was activated')
        SselectionIndex = int(event.widget.curselection()[0])
        Sselection = event.widget.get(SselectionIndex)
        self.Selected.delete(ANCHOR)
        self.Available.delete(self.AList.index(Sselection))
        self.Available.insert(self.AList.index(Sselection), Sselection)

App = DependentLists()

screen_width = App.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = App.winfo_screenheight()
window_height = screen_height - 800
window_width = screen_width - 1400
x_cordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
y_cordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))
App.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))

App.mainloop()
```

Edit: Solution is in BryanOakley's answer (thank you!) and the subsequent comments under that answer.

Comment: Are you wanting this movement if items from one box to the other to _only_ occur on a mouse click, or do you also want the user to be able to use the keyboard to select items and move them from one side to another?

Comment: @BryanOakley, Just on mouseclick

Answer (score 0):

`<<ListboxSelect>>` is triggered whenever the selection changes. This can happen when the user clicks on an item, but it can also happen at other times, such as a user using the keyboard to traverse the listbox, or your code deleting something that was selected.

If your UI should only work on a mouse click, you should be binding to that rather than `<<ListboxSelect>>`.

Comment: a selection and a mouseclick need to occur simultaneously in that case since I don't want the methods to run if I click somewhere inside the ListBox without making an actual selection. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Elsayeda: the selection happens automatically, you don't have to do anything. If you bind to the mouse click you can easily check to see whether you're over an item or not and either allow the selection or disallow it.

Comment: I think the mouseclick event and the subsequent code in my methods are running before the selection event is even registered  because I'm getting an Index error on click and the transfer doesn't occur until I make another selection. Using  the conditional 'if self.Available.curselection():' before the rest of the method is a workaround for the error, but I still have to double click for the transfer to occur (and by extension, run the method twice). The selection does indeed occur automatically but way too late for it to be used by my code.

Comment: _"I think the mouseclick event and the subsequent code in my methods are running before the selection event is even registered"_ - yes, that's how bindings work in tkinter. It sounds like you don't need the selection, you just need to know the item that was clicked on. You can get that without relying on the selection. You can do something like `event.widget.index(f"@{event.x},{event.y}")` to get the index of the item that was clicked on.